# vector::erase doesn't work in class method, but works in main; No Compiler Error, just unexpected results

Tags: c++, vector, erase

I have the following statement in a file x.cpp. Suppliers and location are classes I created.  If I write in my main.cpp

```
Suppliers s;
s.clean_up();
```

and in file x.cpp

```
void Suppliers::clean_up(){
    for(auto i : setter){
        i.second.clear();}}
```

Setter is a public data member of Suppliers

```
 map<std::string,std::vector<location>> setter
```

The map is not cleared when I try to print it.  On the contrary if I have the following in my main, the values in my map are cleared as I would expect.

```
Suppliers s;
for (auto item : s.setter){
     item.second.clear();}
```

I have no Compiler errors, in one case the location vector is erased and in one case it isn't.  The only thing I can think of is that the instance of setter aren't the same.  But because I'm using a method I can't see why this wouldn't work.  Any help would be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 6):

You should iterate using references to your map items

```
for(auto& i : setter)
{
    i.second.clear();
}
```

Otherwise `i` will be a *copy* of each `std::pair<std::string, std::vector<location>>`. So it will `clear()` the vector of the copy, not the actual instance in the `map`.